# print Player result on java

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I can't print my two player result in the Jtextpane area :

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel; 
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public class dice {

    private JFrame frame;
    protected int width;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    dice window = new dice();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public dice() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 784, 945);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblDiceface1 = new JLabel("");
        lblDiceface1.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 99));
        lblDiceface1.setBounds(56, 78, 150, 150);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblDiceface1);

        JLabel lblDiceface2 = new JLabel("");
        lblDiceface2.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 99));
        lblDiceface2.setBounds(294, 78, 150, 150);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblDiceface2);

        JLabel lbloperatingLabel = new JLabel("Score joueur #1 :  \r\n");
        lbloperatingLabel.setBounds(56, 34, 500, 30);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lbloperatingLabel);

        JLabel lblnbdecoup = new JLabel("");
        lblnbdecoup.setBounds(575, 183, 132, 29);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblnbdecoup);

        JTextPane lblResultat = new JTextPane();
        lblResultat.setText("Partie\tJoueur#1\t\tJoueur#2");
        lblResultat.setBounds(56, 588, 443, 285);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblResultat);

        JButton jouer1 = new JButton("Jouer");
        JButton jouer2 = new JButton("Jouer");
        JButton btnNouvellePartie = new JButton("Nouvelle partie");
        //Set Button enable\disable..........................................................................
        jouer1.setEnabled(true);

        jouer1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            //Declare and inisialize the button clicks.......................................................
            int nbDeCoup = 0;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
                //PLAYER1............................................                   
                int face1, face2;
                double temp1, temp2;
                Icon icon, icon2; 
                int resultat;

                //face1..............................................
                temp1 = Math.random() * 6;
                face1 = (int) Math.floor(temp1) + 1;

                icon = new ImageIcon("dice_" + face1 + ".png");
                icon = new ImageIcon(((ImageIcon) icon).getImage().getScaledInstance(150, 150, BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH));
                lblDiceface1.setIcon(icon);


                //face2...............................................
                temp2 = Math.random() * 6;
                face2 = (int) Math.floor(temp2) + 1;

                icon2 = new ImageIcon("dice_" + face2 + ".png");
                icon2 = new ImageIcon(((ImageIcon) icon2).getImage().getScaledInstance(150, 150, BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH));
                lblDiceface2.setIcon(icon2);

                //print score of the player1..........................
                if (face1 == face2){
                    resultat = (face1 + face2) - (nbDeCoup + 1);
                    lbloperatingLabel.setText("Score joueur #1 :  " + face1 + " + " + face2 + " - " + (nbDeCoup + 1) + " = " + resultat);
                    //Set Button enable\disable.......................
                    jouer1.setEnabled(false);
                    jouer2.setEnabled(true);
                    lblResultat.setText(resultat);
                }


                //print button "jouer" clicks of the player1..........
                nbDeCoup++;
                lblnbdecoup.setText("" + nbDeCoup);     
            }
        });
        jouer1.setBounds(575, 133, 132, 34);
        frame.getContentPane().add(jouer1);

        JSeparator separator = new JSeparator();
        separator.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        separator.setBounds(56, 62, 554, 2);
        frame.getContentPane().add(separator);

        JLabel lbloperatingLabel2 = new JLabel("Score joueur #2 :  \r\n");
        lbloperatingLabel2.setBounds(56, 271, 554, 30);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lbloperatingLabel2);

        JSeparator separator_1 = new JSeparator();
        separator_1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        separator_1.setBounds(56, 300, 554, 2);
        frame.getContentPane().add(separator_1);

        JLabel lblface1 = new JLabel("");
        lblface1.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 99));
        lblface1.setBounds(56, 328, 150, 150);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblface1);

        JLabel lblface2 = new JLabel("");
        lblface2.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 99));
        lblface2.setBounds(294, 328, 150, 150);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblface2);

        JLabel lblnbdecoup2 = new JLabel("");
        lblnbdecoup2.setBounds(575, 419, 132, 29);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblnbdecoup2);

        jouer2.setEnabled(false);

        jouer2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            //Declare and inisialize the button clicks................
            int nbDeCoup = 0;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                //PLAYER2............................................
                int face1, face2;
                double temp1, temp2;
                Icon icon, icon2; 
                int resultat;

                //face1...............................................
                temp1 = Math.random() * 6;
                face1 = (int) Math.floor(temp1) + 1;

                icon = new ImageIcon("dice_" + face1 + ".png");
                icon = new ImageIcon(((ImageIcon) icon).getImage().getScaledInstance(150, 150, BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH));
                lblface1.setIcon(icon);

                //face2...............................................
                temp2 = Math.random() * 6;
                face2 = (int) Math.floor(temp2) + 1;

                icon2 = new ImageIcon("dice_" + face2 + ".png");
                icon2 = new ImageIcon(((ImageIcon) icon2).getImage().getScaledInstance(150, 150, BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH));
                lblface2.setIcon(icon2);

                //print score of the player1..........................
                if (face1 == face2){
                    resultat = (face1 + face2) - (nbDeCoup + 1);
                    lbloperatingLabel2.setText("Score joueur #1 :  " + face1 + " + " + face2 + " - " + (nbDeCoup + 1) + " = " + resultat);

                    jouer2.setEnabled(false);
                    btnNouvellePartie.setEnabled(true);
                    lblResultat.setText(resultat);
                }

                //print button "jouer" clicks of the player1..........
                nbDeCoup++;
                lblnbdecoup2.setText("" + nbDeCoup);    
            }
        });
        jouer2.setBounds(575, 363, 132, 34);
        frame.getContentPane().add(jouer2);

        JLabel lblPointage = new JLabel("Pointage :");
        lblPointage.setBounds(56, 542, 200, 30);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblPointage);

        //Set Button enable\disable...................................
        btnNouvellePartie.setEnabled(false);

        btnNouvellePartie.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            }
        });
        btnNouvellePartie.setBounds(514, 556, 233, 34);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNouvellePartie);

        JButton btnQuiter = new JButton("Quiter");
        btnQuiter.setBounds(580, 717, 132, 29);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnQuiter);  
    }
}
```

The thing is when I set the result on the Jtextpane which is "lblResultat" that show the player 1 result and when the player 2 result is printed that erase the player one result, I want to do somthing like

```
lblResultat.setText(player score 1 + player score 2);
```

player score replaced by their variable which is "resultat"

thxxxxx

Answer (score 1):

- Simply use a JTextArea, not a JTextPane
- Add additional lines of text via the `append(...)` method, not the `setText(...)` method.
- Another option is to use a JList, **but actually the best option for displaying columnar data is to use a JTable**.
- Never set the sizes of Swing text components as that cripples the component.
- Put your JTextArea within a JScrollPane.
- While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.